# Convert a const Array to JSON with specific keys

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, json

I have an array like this:

```
const faces= [
    [[128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"],
    [[128512], "grinning face", "20201001"],
    [[128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"],
    [[128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"],
    [[128521], "winking face", "20201001"]
]
```

And I want to convert it to a formatted JSON like this using JavaScript:

```
[
  {
    "id": 128516,
    "name": "grinning face with smiling eyes",
    "date": "20201001"
  },
  {
    "id": 128512,
    "name": "grinning face",
    "date": "20201001"
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try it by yourself? Please add the code you tried and what difficulty you're facing

Comment: Just loop it & put it in jsonobject & then add that into jsonArray. What is the issue with that.

Comment: First step is to pick a single programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const faces = [
  [
    [128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128512], "grinning face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128521], "winking face", "20201001"
  ]
]

let result = []
faces.forEach(item => {
  let a = {
    id: item[0][0],
    name: item[1],
    date: item[2]
  }
  result.push(a)
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Your code works but why keys don't show in string format such as "id" or "name". They show without quotes.

Comment: then just use JSON.stringify(obj) if you need them in that format ;)

Comment: I edited it for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce`:

```js
const faces = [
  [
    [128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128512], "grinning face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"
  ],
  [
    [128521], "winking face", "20201001"
  ]
]

const result = faces.reduce((result, value) => {
  result.push({
    id: value[0][0],
    name: value[1],
    date: value[2]
  })
  return result
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your code works but why keys don't show in string format such as "id" or "name". They show without quotes.

Comment: With " it's a JSON object. This is a pure Javascript object. If you want to have it like yours I can modify the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner code using 'map' functionality of Arrays.

```js
const faces= [
    [[128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"],
    [[128512], "grinning face", "20201001"],
    [[128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"],
    [[128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"],
    [[128521], "winking face", "20201001"]
];

let newObj = []; 

faces.map(eachObj => {
  const obj = {
   id: eachObj[0][0],
   name: eachObj[1],
   date: eachObj[2]
  };
  newObj.push(obj);
});

console.log('New Obj ==>', newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const faces= [
  [[128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"],
  [[128512], "grinning face", "20201001"],
  [[128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"],
  [[128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"],
  [[128521], "winking face", "20201001"]
]
const formatedFaces = faces.reduce((acc, item)=> {
  const obj ={
    id: item[0][0],
    name: item[1],
    date: item[2]
  };
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(formatedFaces))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map`

```js
const faces= [
    [[128516], "grinning face with smiling eyes", "20201001"],
    [[128512], "grinning face", "20201001"],
    [[128578], "slightly smiling face", "20201001"],
    [[128579], "upside-down face", "20201001"],
    [[128521], "winking face", "20201001"]
]

let result = faces.map(([ [id], name, date ]) => ({ id, name, date }))

console.log(result)
```